# Can I bind a ui:inputCheckBox value to the inverse of an object field's value?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I came across this occurrence while developing a lightning component. I'm trying to bind a checkbox value to the inverse of the value of the `NetworkMember.PreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail` field. But the value does not change when the checkbox is clicked/changed. Here's a code sample:

```
<aura:attribute name='member' type='NetworkMember'/>

<div class="slds-order--1 slds-medium-order--1 slds-large-order--1">
    <ui:inputCheckbox value='{!!v.member.PreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail}' change='{!c.allPrefDisabled}'/>
    <label class="slds-form-element__label">Recieve Emails</label>
</div>
```

When I do this (note the `!` in the value attr), the field's value never changes from it's original state, despite changing it in the UI. However, if I remove the `!` like so:

```
<aura:attribute name='member' type='NetworkMember'/>

<div class="slds-order--1 slds-medium-order--1 slds-large-order--1">
    <ui:inputCheckbox value='{!v.member.PreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail}' change='{!c.allPrefDisabled}'/>
    <label class="slds-form-element__label">Recieve Emails</label>
</div>
```

The value is updated accordingly. Of course, I could change the label to `Disable Emails` as a workaround but I can't imagine that this is expected behavior. Has anyone observed this before and is this a platform bug, or is there some reasoning for this?

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: I also tried using the lightning function `not` listed here: [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm) as opposed to the `!` and observed the same behavior.

Comment: When you use the evaluation operator you may be loosing the binding to the field

Comment: @Eric I'd assume something along those lines is happening. Although I would think there would be a way to get the value reflected in the UI either through `event.getSource().get('v.value')` or `component.find('AURA_ID').get('v.value')` or some similar mechanism but those values never change from their initial state. I thought it was odd because I never had this issue using Visualforce.

Comment: I have said something similar with process builder. "Never had these issues with workflows" lol. It will get there just may take some time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add the negation to the `value` property it turns the expression to a `FunctionCallValue`. Since it is no longer directly mapped to an attribute (as it is with the single `!`), clicking the checkbox no longer updates the original attribute. Imagine if instead of a simple negation there was a more complicated expression like `value="{!v.myAttr.foo == 'meep'}"`. The framework doesn't know what to set back to this expression when the checkbox is clicked, so it ignores it.

In fact, if you go to Setup --> Lightning Components and check the "Enable Debug Mode" checkbox, you'll see a similar error in the console:

> aura_dev.js:3977 AttributeSet.set(): unable to override the value for 'value=function (cmp, fn) { return !(cmp.get("v.myAttr.foo")); }'. FunctionCallValues declared in markup are constant.

There's probably a better way to handle this, but one workaround is to create a new attribute that is bound to the `ui:inputCheckbox` value and then in the change handler update `v.member.PreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail`. Here's a simplified example:

Markup:

```
<aura:attribute name="checkboxValue" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
<ui:inputCheckbox value='{!v.checkboxValue}' change='{!c.changed}'/>
```

Controller:

```
changed: function(cmp) {
    var val = cmp.get("v.checkboxValue");
    cmp.set("v.member.PreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail", !val);
}
```

In your case you'd probably want to set the initial value of `checkboxValue` to the negation of `member.PreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail` in the init handler (or similar).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation here. Out of curiosity, is it on the road map to support this type of binding?

Comment: No, there are no plans to add bindings to FunctionCallValue's like in your example.